# Correct way to stop ReadAsStreamAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httprequest, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

My code looks like:

```
_req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _uri);
_response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

var rawResponse = new byte[_maxContentLength];

using (var responseStream = await _response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    int read;
    int offset = 0;

    do
    {
        read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(rawResponse, 0, rawResponse.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        html += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawResponse, 0, read);
        offset += read;

        if (offset > _maxContentLength)
        {
            return Error("Too big");
        }

    } while (read != 0);
}
```

and is "return Error()" enough to free stream and sockets to get next url?

//edit:
For some pages `await responseStream.ReadAsync` hangs and never returns

Comment: You need to put a using() around the response as well. That should free up all the resources.

Comment: _response is disposed in another place because it is classwide variable

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a CancellationTokenSource and calling Cancel on that when you want to stop.  I'm assuming that you can't read the Content-Length header at the beginning because the response is chunk encoded?

Comment: Content-Length isn't solution because _response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false); always download all content when disposed, I don't know is any way to close the connection without downloading

Comment: The question was `why don't you check the value of Content-Length before you start downloading`? Besides - if you don't call HttpResponseMessage.Dispose on the response object, the connection and the stream will not be released until the garbage collector runs.

Comment: I'm checking but not for every site it is present

Comment: @ekapek Content-Length is always present unless the sender is using chunked encoding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The connection is managed completely independently of the lifetime of the HttpResponseMessage.  When you Dispose the HttpClient instance it tries to close the Connnection, but that is completely unnecessary because the ServiceConnectionPoint class manages the pool of connections.